# Aggregate info by quarters in data.table, setting a new name to column used in by

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have this data.table that is a result from aggregating a bigger one:

```
data.table(Period = c('2018.01', '2018.02'), sales = c(8850, 7950), qty = c(650, 650))

    Period sales qty
1: 2018.01  8850 650
2: 2018.02  7950 650
```

What I need to achieve and can't get a way to do it, is to aggregate the info by quarters, so the result would be:

```
data.table(Period = c('2018.01', '2018.02', '2018Q1', '2018'), sales = c(8850, 7950, 16800, 16800), qty = c(650, 650, 1300, 1300))

   Period sales  qty
1: 2018.01  8850  650
2: 2018.02  7950  650
3:  2018Q1 16800 1300
4:    2018 16800 1300
```

I've tried with: `dt = rbind(dt, dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(Period), .SDcols = c('sales', 'qty')])`

but I get duplicated columns:

```
    Period  ums men
1: 2018.01 8850 650
2: 2018.02 7950 650
3: 2018.01 8850 650
4: 2018.02 7950 650
```

Besides, I'd need to rename the Period cell with Q1 (Q2, Q3, Q4) for the quarters and only the year for the total. How could it be done?

**EDIT**

Although the accepted answer is correct, I've reworked it so that I didn't need to add extra columns nor install new libraries:

```
DT = data.table(Period = c('2018.01', '2018.02'), sales = c(8850, 7950), qty = c(650, 650))

DT$Period = as.double(str_replace(DT$Period, "\\.", ""))
ints      = setInterval(2018)
dt        = DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(Period = cut(Period, breaks = ints$i, labels = ints$q)), .SDcols = c('sales', 'qty')]
dt        = rbind(dt, dt[Period %in% ints$q, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(Period = '2018'), .SDcols = c('sales', 'qty')], fill = T)
DT$Period = paste(substr(DT$Period, 1, 4), ".", right(DT$Period, 2), sep = "")
DT        = rbind(DT, dt)
```

I needed to create this auxiliary function:

```
setInterval = function (year) {
   y = year * 100
   return (list(
      i = c(y, y + 3, y + 6, y + 9, y + 12),
      q = paste(year, '.', c('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'), sep = '')
   ))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt <- data.table(Period = c('2018.01', '2018.02'), sales = c(8850, 7950), qty = c(650, 650))
library(zoo)
dt$Period_YQ <- as.character(as.yearqtr(paste(dt$Period, "01", sep="."), "%Y.%m.%d"))
dt$Period_Y <- strtrim(dt$Period, 4)

dt1 <- dt[,.SD,.SDcols=c(1:3)]
dt2 <- dt[,lapply(.SD,sum), by="Period_YQ", .SDcols = c('sales', 'qty')]
colnames(dt2) <- c('Period','sales', 'qty')
dt3 <- dt[,lapply(.SD,sum), by="Period_Y", .SDcols = c('sales', 'qty')]
colnames(dt3) <- c('Period','sales', 'qty')
rbind(dt1,dt2,dt3)
```

Comment: Note that the RHS of the line setting PeriodYQ could be just:  `format(as.yearqtr(dt$Period, "%Y.%m"))`

Answer (score 0):

A similar but different approach that uses `lubridate` and `dplyr`:

Convert your `Period` to a `DATE` format. I like using `lubridate::parse_date_time`. Note that I also create new columns for each `Year` and `Quarter`:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% 
      mutate(Period = parse_date_time(Period, "ym")) %>%
      mutate(Year = year(Period)) %>% 
      mutate(Quarter = quarter(Period))
```

Then you calculate the `Yearly` and `Quarterly` sums separately:

```
Yearly <- df %>% 
          group_by(Year) %>%
          summarise(Y.sales = sum(sales), Y.qty = sum(qty))

Quarterly <- df %>%
             group_by(Year, Quarter) %>%
             summarise(Q.sales = sum(sales), Q.qty = sum(qty))
```

Finally, you combine all the data using `full_join`:

```
final <- full_join(Yearly, Quarterly, by=c("Year")) %>% 
         full_join(., df, by=c("Year","Quarter"))
```

This gives you a tidier (*IMO*) output organized by `Year`, `Quarter`, then `Period`:

```
   Year Y.sales Y.qty Quarter Q.sales Q.qty     Period sales   qty
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dttm> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2018   16800  1300       1   16800  1300 2018-01-01  8850   650
2  2018   16800  1300       1   16800  1300 2018-02-01  7950   650
```